# Is hashinfo equivalent to peer ID in Mainline DHT?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I am working on Mainline DHT and I don't understand one nuance.

Here: https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html writes: "A "distance metric" is used to compare two node IDs or a node ID and an info hash for "closeness."

Also writes: "Announce that the peer, controlling the querying node, is downloading a torrent on a port. announce_peer has four arguments: "id" containing the node ID of the querying node, "info_hash" containing the info hash of the torrent, "port" containing the port as an integer, and the "token" received in response to a previous get_peers query."

So, for example, we have a peer with ID 223456789zxcvbnmasdf which IP is 86.23.145.714 and port is: 7853
I know that this peer downloaded 2 torrent files with info hashes: 023456789zxcvbnmasdf and 123456789zxcvbnmasdf.

So how exactly my k-bucket record should look like?
Like this:

```
{"id": "223456789zxcvbnmasdf", "ip": "86.23.145.714", "port": "7853", "torrents": ["023456789zxcvbnmasdg", "123456789zxcvbnmasdh"]} ?
```

Or should torrent files be like an "equivalent" record (with duplicated ips and ports) in k-buckets along with peer:

```
{"id": "223456789zxcvbnmasdf", "ip": "86.23.145.714", "port": "7853"},

{"id": "023456789zxcvbnmasdg", "ip": "86.23.145.714", "port": "7853"},

{"id": "123456789zxcvbnmasdh", "ip": "86.23.145.714", "port": "7853"} ?
```

I am asking because this is not just implementation nuance. Because "k" is normally 20 or some other integer in all clients. So if I would use k-buckets to store torrent files as full-right members, I would have less space to store real peers data.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: @the8472 yeah, question is duplicated, but I am sorry, I still don't see a concrete answer. Even more - your answer confused me: "A node is a storage for multiple key-value-pairs where the keys are close to its ID."

So the question is the same - how exactly node ID are mapped with info hashes in the data structure? For example, if we rely on my given example in first message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k-buckets datastructure is an implementation detail of bit-torrent protocol so that peers reply quickly enough to `FIND_PEERS` and `FIND_VALUE`.

What I do in my kademlia implementation is that keep the the routing table in a python dictionary and I compute the nearest peers under the 5 seconds by default which is the timeout I use to wait for a UDP reply. To achieve that I need to keep the routing table below 1 000 000 entries.

Like I said above, the routing table is a simple python `dict` that maps `peerid` to `(address, port)`.

The routing table stores peers not values ie. not `infohash` addresses.

When I receive a `FIND_PEERS` message, the program replies with the following code:

```
async def peers(self, address, uid):
    """Remote procedure that returns peers that are near UID"""
    log.debug("[%r] find peers uid=%r from %r", self._uid, uid, address)
    # XXX: if this takes more than 5 seconds (see RPCProtocol) it
    # will timeout in the other side.
    uids = nearest(self._replication, self._peers.keys(), uid)
    out = [self._peers[x] for x in uids]
    return out
```

When I receive a `FIND_VALUE` message, the program replies with the following code:

```
async def value(self, address, key):
    """Remote procedure that returns the associated value or peers that
    are near KEY"""
    log.debug("[%r] value key=%r from %r", self._uid, key, address)
    out = await lookup(key)
    if out is None:
        # value is not found, reply with peers that are near KEY
        out = nearest(self._replication, self._peers.keys(), uid)
        return (b"PEERS", out)
    else:
        return (b"VALUE", out)
```

Here is the definition of `nearest`:

```
def nearest(k, peers, uid):
    """Return K nearest to to UID peers in PEERS according to XOR"""
    # XXX: It only works with len(peers) < 10^6 more than that count
    # of peers and the time it takes to compute the nearest peers will
    # timeout after 5 seconds on the other side. See RPCProtocol and
    # Peer.peers.
    return nsmallest(k, peers, key=functools.partial(operator.xor, uid))
```

That is it sorts the `peers` according to their `peerid` and return the `k` smallest. `nsmallest` is supposed to be an optimized version of `sort(peers, key=functools.partial(operator.xor, uid))[:k]` where `uid` is a `peerid` or `infohash` (respectively `FIND_PEERS` and `FIND_VALUE`).

Now back at your question(s):

> Is hashinfo equivalent to peer ID in Mainline DHT?

`hashinfo` is a hash-something that is the same kind of hash as `peerid` ie. they are **possible** keys in the routing table. That is, torrent files are associated with a hash, peers are associated with the same kind of hash called `peerid`. And peers have the "ownership" of keys that near their `peerid`. BUT `hashinfo` are not stored in the routing table or k-buckets if you prefer. `hashinfo` are stored in another mapping that associate `hashinfo` hash with their value(s).

> I am asking because this is not just implementation nuance. Because "k" is normally 20 or some other integer in all clients. So if I would use k-buckets to store torrent files as full-right members, I would have less space to store real peers data.

There is mis-understanding here about the same thing I try explain above. `hashinfo` are keys in storage dictionary. Whereas `peerid` are keys in the routing table aka. k-buckets datastructure. They both have the same format because that is how the kademlia routing algorithm work. You must be able to compare `hashinfo` with `peerid` with `xor` to be able to tell which peers "own" which `hashinfo` value.

As you can see in the second snippet, when a another peer ask for a value associated with an hash, it calls `lookup(key)` that is something like `storage.get(key)` except in my case the code stores values in a database.

---

Maybe there is a mis-understanding about the fact that k-buckets are used to store *DHT routing* information. And that **on top of that**, torrent protocol use the DHT to store ***torrent* routing** information.

---

For what it is worth, [qadom's peer.py file](https://github.com/amirouche/qadom/blob/master/qadom/peer.py) is where I implement a DHT inspired from kademlia (except I use 256 bits hash and forgo `alpha` and `k` parameters and use a single `REPLICATION` parameter). The code works *most of the  time* check the tests.

Also, there is another project I got inspiration from called simply [kademlia](https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia) that (try to?) implement k-buckets.

As far as I understand, torrent DHT routing looks like [qadom `bag` functions](https://github.com/amirouche/qadom/blob/b1bf5762ee62a958f5c9e9ea991d6f7c792fbece/qadom/peer.py#L380-L442) except the receiving peer must authenticate the announcement, whereas in qadom bags are free-for-all.

Also, check the original kademlia paper.

Answer (score 1):

How you structure your data internally is up to you. All it has to do is fulfill the contract of the specification. In principle one could associate torrents with buckets based on the xor distance – e.g. for resource accounting reasons – but most implementations keep the routing table and the storage separate.

The primary routing table only contains *nodes*, structural members of the DHT overlay itself. Torrents on the other hand are not part of the overlay. They're data stored on top of the overlay, the hash table abstraction. Hence the name, Distributed Hash Table. I.e. they exist on different abstraction levels.

Comment: Yes! This explains the same thing I am trying to explain while being less verbose.